# How to check maximum core count,Storage account count in azure resource manager portal using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have to check maximum core count and storage count in azure ARM using powershell. when i give this command (Get-AzureRmSubscription -current -ExtendedDetails).MaxStorageAccounts It shows the error as "Get-AzureRmSubscription : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'current'." please let me know how to get the count. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `Get-AzureRmStorageUsage` to get current usage and limits.

   [image]
2. Use `Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location YourLocation` to get the core usage and limits.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the update.Similarly can we able to get the usage of Virtualnetwork,AvailabiltysetResourceGroup. I have tried it.But couldn't get it.Please let me know if there are any commands.